# How to get rid of "\r" a the end of the line comming from pipeline in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

```
#!/bin/bash
sourcenode=$1
destnode=$2
path1=/root/test
ssh root@"${sourcenode}" -t "echo "${path1}" | xargs -IDIR find DIR " |
while read line
do
        ssh root@"${sourcenode}" -t "stat -c "%a" $line | xargs -IDIR ssh root@"${destnode}" chmod DIR $line"
done
```

This script is supposed to copy only permissions between two remote machines: source and destination.
On source and destination machines there is a folder (`/root/test/`) with few files.
For some reason on the first line read it adds `\r` at the end of it.
I tried a few things to get rid of it, but with no avail.

I get this error.

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
stat: cannot stat `/root/test\r': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you try to simplify the script by leaving out parts that do not affect the problem? Which operating systems are involved, locally and on the remote nodes?

Comment: Is there a chance you used a window based text editor ? or copy/paste ? if yes, try dos2unix on your script. or save with a line ending in unix format.

Comment: I was creating the script on linux machine using vim. The problem is that I this line: ssh root@"${sourcenode}" -t "echo "${path1}" | xargs -IDIR find DIR " is listing the files inside the folder without any problem. But when I uncomment part of the code with loop, for some reason i can see '\r' added at the end of the first line. So instead of this line looking like that: /root/test  it looks like that: /root/test\r    I can't get rid of it.

Comment: Have you tried removing `-t` and why are you using it at all?

Answer (score 4):

Oh dear, triple ssh pipeline with a loop and useless xargs, you found the worst way of doing this.

The `\r` you are seeing appears to be a leftover of the newline that is getting across the pipeline. You should remove the `-t` option, it may be the cause of your problems. Output meant to display in virtual terminals is different from the normal stream.

Moreover, `echo ${path1} | xargs` is completely superfluous, just run `find ${path1}`, you only have one input line to `xargs` anyway. The same goes for the second `xargs`. Of course, you can put everything in `find`. Try:

```
ssh root@"${sourcenode}" "find ${path1} -printf 'chmod %m \"f\"\n'"
```

And pipe this into the next command (*NOT* into a local bash loop but feed it directly into the ssh to destnode).

Comment: Indeed, the spurious `-t` is the cause of the spurious CR.